# Is there any way to set up a proxy on Android device to intercept an application traffic by a computer that is not connected to network?

Tags: android, networking, proxy, 5g

I want to intercept and modify an android application traffic using Burp Suite. Unfortunately i dont have an internet connection at my home but my phone has 5g internet. Is there any way or application tahat allows us to set up a proxy on my phone and control it from my computer?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [HttpCanary](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.guoshi.httpcanary&hl=es)

You don't monitor this with the computer, but the application generates json internally with requests and responses information and you can transfer this to your computer for better analisys.

With wifi network,you could use [CharlesProxy](https://www.charlesproxy.com/)